# Handling quotes and trademark symbols in front end

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a `Angular 6` application where I need to display the items from API.
Sometimes name of the item in the API response will be having trademark symbols in Unicode format and sometimes it will be having in inch symbols.

```
Ex1: "name": "7\" x 14.25\" Folding ..."
Ex2: "name": "Living\u2122 by Universal ..."
```

I tried to decode the name using `decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"' + name.replace('"', '\\"') + '"'));` in `typescript`. It works very well in case of Trademark symbol (Ex2) but fails in the case of Ex1. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerText` directive

```
<span [innerText]="ex1"></span>
```

or create a pipe for sanitizing by using `DomSanitizer` which is more flexible if you can receive names with html also.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div [innerHtml]="ex1 | safeHtml"></div>
<div [innerHtml]="ex2 | safeHtml"></div>
```

Take a look on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giqm1b) example

Comment: I have created safe-pipe.ts file and imported files in app module and inserted `[innerHtml]` in html, but trademark symbol is not working. Have i missed something ?(i have refered the above stackblitz example).

Comment: Can you share the piece of code? It's hard to say what could you missed

Comment: In stackblitz, I have not used any pipe but it is still working fine.
Take a look on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfggab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes, you can use `innerHTML` directive directly without a pipe or as I mention in answer you can try `innerText` directive instead `innerHTML` if it's only a text. Pipe is necessary when you received names which contain html tags. I hope I helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [innerHTML] property
E.g.,

```
name:string = "7\" x 14.25\" Folding ...";
<p [innerHTML]="name"></p>
```